# Parquet Output From Kafka Connect to S3

Tags: apache-kafka, parquet, apache-kafka-connect

I see Kafka Connect can write to S3 in Avro or JSON formats. But there is no Parquet support. How hard would this be to add?

Comment: Added! See: https://twitter.com/karantasis/status/1181701302608285698?s=19 and: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/pull/241

Comment: Parquet support is now available as part of the 5.4 release of Kafka Connect S3 sink

Comment: Yes you can! I wrote an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73926873/9192415)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with Confluent 5.4.0, there is official support for Parquet output to S3.

Answer (score 2):

The Qubole connector supports writing out parquet - https://github.com/qubole/streamx

Answer (score 1):

Try `secor`:
https://github.com/pinterest/secor

Can work with AWS S3, google cloud, Azure's blob storage etc.

Note that the solution you choose must have key features like:
Guarantee writing each message exactly once, load distribution, fault tolerance, monitoring, partitioning data etc.

`Secor` has it all and as stated above, can easily work with other "s3" style services..